# Python interpolation of satellite ground tracks

Tags: python, interpolation, latitude-longitude, satellite

I'm trying to interpolate the following satellite ground track:

[image]

The problem is the discontinuity at (lon,lat)->(0,0), which causes a poor fitting curve in this region:

[image]

I'm not sure if a parametric interpolation will be the best approach, for now I have just applied a linear interpolation:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

df = pd.read_table('groundtracks', sep='\t')

x = df['lon']
y = df['lat']

f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='linear')

xnew = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), num=x.count()*2)
ynew = f(xnew)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't interpolate near 0, because the satellite was there at two very different points in time.

You should add 360° to the second half of your data (which might correspond with the upper left curve), so that you get a continuous curve from about -30° to 360°. Then interpolate. Then perform the reverse operation: `lon[lon>180] -= 360`.

Comment: Thanks, it is a nice workaround solution, but the data needs some prior manipulation in order to split by quadrants as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you might also try splitting the track into its two distinct halves, and interpolating them individually.